# Вычисления возраста на дату в прошлом

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

Есть DataFrame и в нем есть два столбца `DAT_BIRTH_CUST` и `DAT_CUST_OPEN`.

Необходимо вычислить возраст клиента на дату покупки товара, т.е. что-то вроде:

```
DAT_CUST_OPEN - DAT_BIRTH_CUST = AGE
```

Типы данных:

```
dtypes:
DAT_BIRTH_CUST      1000 non-null datetime64[ns]
DAT_CUST_OPEN       1000 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

Нужно вычислить возраст и сохранить в отдельную колонку DataFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df["age"] = (df["DAT_CUST_OPEN"] - df["DAT_BIRTH_CUST"]).astype("<m8[Y]")
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно:)

Comment: что у вас с кавычками?

Comment: @SKIP, такая "красота" получается если писать ответ с iPhone ;) Исправил...